# How to get current time value in GMT in ILog JRule

Tags: date, time, gmt, ilog, jrules

I have a business requirement where I have to a take one action where current GMT time is between 3 to 11 else I have to take other action.
One way to do is to take the current GMT time as input from the caller. 
I want to explore the possibility, whether I can get the current GMT time with Rule and use that for my decision.

Answer (score 0):

Use java.util.Date in a Java class in the XOM with the necessary methods and then verbalize them in the BOM as rules.